# Is there a way to reference a class in an xml sheet using css?

Tags: css, xml

Here is the Xml, I was wondering how you would reference the class "down" using css so I can style all similar code sections the same? This is just a clip I have the css correctly referenced at the start of my xml file

```
  <stock class="down">
     <symbol>AAPL</symbol>
     <company>Apple Computer, Inc.</company>
     <lastSale>$15.26</lastSale>
     <netChange>-0.17</netChange>
     <pChange>-1.10%</pChange>
     <volume>5.548</volume>
  </stock>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="styles.css"?>
<stock class="down">
    <symbol>AAPL</symbol>
    <company>Apple Computer, Inc.</company>
    <lastSale>$15.26</lastSale>
    <netChange>-0.17</netChange>
    <pChange>-1.10%</pChange>
    <volume>5.548</volume>
</stock>
```

---

Your `styles.css` CSS:

```
.down {
    //Your styles here
}
```

Or:

```
stock.down {
    //Your styles here
}
```

Or:

```
[class~=down] {
    //Your styles here
}
```

Or:

```
stock[class~=down] {
    //Your styles here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! the first example does not work the the second does the charm!

Comment: Added a few. Depending on use case, some of these will not work.